# Difference in Matplotlib method

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.8

I have dataframe below as subset of my data. The full dataset has "day_of_week" from Monday - Sunday and "hour" in 24-hour format.

```
day_of_week hour    record
0   Friday  00:00:00    23655
1   Friday  01:00:00    11806
2   Friday  02:00:00    6846
3   Friday  03:00:00    4284
4   Friday  04:00:00    5706
5   Friday  05:00:00    21557
6   Friday  06:00:00    71883
```

Below are data types:

```
day_of_week    category
hour             object
record            int64
dtype: object
```

I want to create multiple subplots, one plot for each day_of_week to show variation in record over 24-hour period. I try to do only for "Friday" first.

Method 1 and I got an error message:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.plot('hour', 'record', data = activity_by_hour)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'
```

Method 2 and a line chart is produced:

```
activity_by_hour.loc[activity_by_hour.day_of_week == 'Friday']\
.plot('hour', 'record', 
        title = 'Friday',
        xlabel = "Hour", 
        ylabel = "Ride ('000)",
        legend = "", 
        linestyle = '--', linewidth = 2)

plt.xticks(ticks = (4 * 60 * 60) * np.arange(6)) # 4 hours interval consists of 14,400 seconds
plt.yticks(ticks = np.arange(0, 3.5e5, 5e4), labels = [int(num) for num in np.arange(0, 3.5e5, 5e4)/1000]);
```

[image]

What are the difference in both methods? How can I draw similar chart for Monday - Sunday in one figure that shows 7 lines for each day? I tried "for loop" and I end up with 7 charts, anyway, not a subplot.

Comment: The first method directly uses matplotlib. The second method uses pandas plotting library. Pandas plotting builds on matplotlib, and always acts on a dataframe. Pandas has some convenience functions that a.o. know to handle time objects. Note that there also is seaborn which further simplifies statistics related plots.

Comment: @JohanC ok, great info. does this mean Matplotlib is not capable of plotting time object (i.e. daily, hourly data)? It seems that Pandas plotting library doesn't allow to plot multiple lines in a single figure. Is that true?

Comment: If you need to plot more on the same subplot with pandas, you can do `ax = activity_by_hour.loc[....].plot(...)` and reuse the returned subplot `ax` for the next plot: `ax = activity_by_hour.loc[....].plot(..., ax=ax)`.  Matplotlib allows a lot of things, but some data needs to be "massaged" to fits its numeric format. Pandas knows a lot of the massaging tricks.